# Implement Form — Datasource — create () on opening AX Form

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I am infant to AX and this is my First Ax Post as developer,

We had table "Product Category" with few columns on designing the form for the table , On opening the form We are getting the first record.

My required is to take the Form for New Record on it's opening ,Where all the text boxes of the form should be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the blank record to be displayed in the form if there are no records in the table then set property `InsertIfEmpty` on form datasource to `Yes`

[image]

Otherwise, if you need the blank record to be displayed in the form every time it opens, then call `this.task(#taskNew);` or `YourDataSourceName_ds.create();` in `run` method after `super`.